# How do you reset a Chosen multiple select field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a form with a multiple select field, created using Formtastic and Chosen.

This form has a multiple select field, here is the rails code for it:

```
 = semantic_form_for 'post', :url => action_name_post_path(@post), :html => {:method => :put}, :remote => true do |f|
    = f.input :blogs, :label => _("Blog"), :as => :select, :multiple => :true, :input_html => {:class => "chzn-select"}, :collection => Blog.all
```

I would like to reset the input field using jQuery (the form is submitted and reset remotely), and I can't seem to figure out how to remove the selected elements//clear the input field. The issue is that chosen changes the input field so it isn't a simple text area.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you post the link to your page? that might give us (SO) a clue as to how you can reset it with JS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.chzn-select').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Answer (score 14):

Seems like  combination of the two answers works for me:

```
$('.chosen-select option').prop('selected', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

This deselects all options and also resets the chosen drop down.

http://jsfiddle.net/donkeysauras/j9yuL/ <-- working example

Comment: The answer by suke is a better option; this method will be very slow if you have many options in your select menus

Comment: yeah.. it is slow, you don't need to call the trigger for each option element. You have to trigger only for the select element, then it is blazing fast. Here is my edit:  http://jsfiddle.net/j9yuL/126/

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$('form#form_id').find('select').each(function(i, element) {
    $(element).chosen('destroy');
    $(element).prop("selectedIndex", -1);
    $(element).chosen();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the `multiple select` using `jQuery` as follows

```
$('.chzn-select option').prop('selected', false);
```

Where the `class name` of your select is `chzn-select`.

[**An working example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RmEab/).

Answer (score 1):

from [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Updating Chosen Dynamically

If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

In my case it was

```
jQuery("#my-select-box").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

`my-select-box` is id of selectbox.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that worked for me.
multiselect values are an array so you should do it this way:

$('#elementID').val([]).trigger('chosen:updated');

Answer (score 0):

For whoever may have ended up on this question (there are multiple and they need to be combined), Chosen has updated their syntax--use this instead:

```
$('.chzn-select').val('').trigger('chosen');
```

where `'.chzn-select'` can be switched out for `'select'`, `'#yourSelect'` or whatever other method of selection you wish to use.

Check out:

- [How do I reset a jquery-chosen select option with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery)
- http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events

Answer (score 0):

This works fine to me

```
$('.reset-btn').click(function(){
    var form = $(this).closest('form').get(0);
    form.reset();
    $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Basically i force the form reset and update chosen after reset.
 :D

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your chosen settings. It worked for me:

```
$('.chzn-select-no-search').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
$('#.chosen-select').val('').prop('selected', false).trigger('chosen:updated')
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this could work:

```
$('#client_filter').html(' '); //this worked
```

NOT WORKING:

```
$('#client_filter').val('').trigger('change') ; //not working
$('#client_filter').val('').trigger('chosen:updated') ; //not working
$('#client_filter').val('').trigger('liszt:updated') ; //not working
```