# Clear input textbox programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Chosen reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897760/jquery-chosen-reset)

I'm using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin on my project.

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/gFzzc/

The problem is, I can't reset chosen input textbox programmaticaly. How to do it when I click clear button?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543888/how-do-you-reset-a-chosen-multiple-select-field-using-jquery

Comment: See this link http://jsfiddle.net/VSpa3/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pTf5z/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.search-choice-close').click();
});
```

You might narrow down the scope a bit in case of multiple controls.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use the correct version of Chosen, taken from here:

- https://raw.github.com/harvesthq/chosen/master/chosen/chosen.jquery.js

Then, simply reset the value of the `select` and trigger *"liszt:updated"* event:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".chzn-select").val("").trigger("liszt:updated");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gFzzc/13/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

Give Id to the button:
say clear_chosen

and then trigger close button:

javascript code::

```
$("#clear_chosen").click(function(){
    $(".search-choice-close").click();
});
```

Write the code inside this block::

```
  $(function () {
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly hack, but works:

**Demo:** [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z52gy/2/)

**Code:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").next('.chzn-container').find('.search-choice').remove();
    $(".chzn-select").val('');
    $(".chzn-select").next('.chzn-container').find('.search-field input').focus();
});
```