# How to clear the select boxes

Tags: jquery-chosen

I am hoping this will be a simple answer,  I have used chosen drop downs for filtering the records.  I have added another button for reseting the filter values.

I want to clear the chosen drop down on the "Reset" click.

I did try changing the selected values,  but no luck.

Any pointers?

Comment: Could you show us some code of what have you tried please?

Comment: tried setting the value to blank: $(".category-filter").val("");

Comment: and other thing i tried is to set first option as selected:  $(".psl-filter").find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a jquery-chosen select option with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got answer to my question,  it was asked in the [GitHub for Choosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1679) plugin.

Here is the code that works like charm:-

```
          $('.dropdownclass option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
          $('.dropdownclass').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: With newer jQuery you need to use the `.prop('selected', false);` like `$('.dropdownclass option:selected').prop('selected', false); $('.dropdownclass').trigger('chosen:updated');`

Answer (score 0):

your answer:

```
$(".category-filter").val("")
```

Should work if its got the class "category-filter", and attached in the button .click() function, and within the document.ready function. - Is the option value "" actually a select option that can be selected? as I believe it needs to be for this to work?

A fiddle to show..

http://jsfiddle.net/UmV6p/3/

Comment: James,  this works for default select box,  however i am formatting it using the Choosen plugin,  and code above is not having any impact so far.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first reset it and then update chosen dynamically.

```
$(".category-filter").val(""); 

$(".category-filter").trigger("chosen:updated");     //version v1.0.0

$(".category-filter").trigger("chzn:updated");     //other than version v1.0.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mahesh,  sorry but this didn't worked either.