# jQuery how to dynamically add select element and reset choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a dynamic form in the Play Framework, but I'm not very experienced with javascript. I'm trying to build off of [this jQuery example](http://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/) that allows the dynamic addition of fields. Instead of adding only a text field, I want to add a text field and a select box each time. The tricky part is that even if there is a `selected` item, I want the dynamically added select box to be reset.

Here is my attempt to do this, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery/11365340#11365340)

```css
 $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
   var $wrapper=$('.multi-fields', this);
   $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
     var obj=$('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
     // This following line is incorrect...
     obj.find('.blank').prop('selected', true).end().trigger('chosen:updated');
   }
   );
   $('.multi-field .remove-field',
   $wrapper).click(function() {
     if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1) $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
   }
   );
 }
 );
```

```html
<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">
  <label>Stuff</label>
  <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-fields">
      <div class="multi-field">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="stuff[]"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select>
              <option class="blank" value="">Select a car</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
              <option value="mercedes" selected>Mercedes</option>
              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Since it uses the `clone()` function, if "Mercedes" is selected, then dynamically added `select` dropdowns will also have "Mercedes" selected. How can I make the new `select`s display the blank choice?

Thanks!

**EDIT** - updated my code to reflect the fact that my `input` and `select` tags are encapsulated by `div`s

Comment: why clone when you can create a new element to insert?

Comment: Good question. I suppose it's because the original jsfiddle example I found used `clone()`. This question is actually from the context of a web application using the Play framework, and in there I am dynamically adding to a view template that contains a select element like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needs to remove the attribute selected from the option tag.

For that you can use removeAttr method

Here is the complete code that does what you described.

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        var obj = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').end().find('option').removeAttr('selected').focus();
    });

    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
```

Just added `.end().find('option').removeAttr('selected')` to your code :)

I hope I helped..

Find the code here : https://jsfiddle.net/yrchyndk/

Comment: I like your solution because it is more concise. One thing that I would change is keep the focus on the text field, so I used this `$('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).                find('input').val('').focus().end().                find('option').removeAttr('selected');` https://jsfiddle.net/frkjyv87/2/

Answer (score 3):

The "obj" variable becomes the input node selected in the end of this expression:

```
var obj = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
```

But you should do the trick with select node, in your case it is "obj"`s sibling.

```
 obj.siblings('select').find('.blank').prop('selected', true).end().trigger('chosen:updated');});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xogeufa2/1/

Also, if "input" and "select" nodes are enveloped in div tags, they loose their sibling relations. So in this case, you should find another way, to get the "select". For example, through parents:

```
obj.closest('.multi-field').find('select').find('.blank').prop('selected', true).end().trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ymd7ug7/2/

Comment: I over-simplified my example a little bit. In my actual application, I have a `div` surrounding the `input` and `select` elements. Thus, when I try your solution in that case it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/2ymd7ug7/1/ How do I change the `siblings()` line to work if they are inside of divs?

Comment: Well, in your case "select" and "input" nodes are not siblings anymore, instead, their parents became. In this case it would be easier to climb up to "multi-field", and then look through all it`s children for a "select" node. After "select" was found, do the trick. Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/2ymd7ug7/2/

ps: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Today I learned about `siblings()` and `closest()` =)