# Clear multi select dropdown using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to clear a multi-select dropdown using javascript as shown by the image below

[image]

Class

```
    [MultiSelect("GetLookUps", 6)]
    public int[] HoldItemsArr { get; set; }
```

Chtlm

```
<div class="row form-group">
 @Html.RequiredLabelFor(model => model.HoldItemsArr, new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
 <div class="col-md-7">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoldItemsArr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" } })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoldItemsArr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 if (($("#ReasonForLeaving").val() == 15)) {
     $("#ResignationInfo").show();
 }
 else {
     // I tried all the option below 
     $('#HoldItemsArr').length = 0;
     $("#HoldItemsArr option:selected").prop("selected", false);
     $("#HoldItemsArr").val('')
     $("#HoldItemsArr").multiSelect("clearSelection");
 }
```

Comment: please show the HTML code of the select dropdown

Comment: @Aakash More chtml Added

Comment: @EricAimeTchatchoua are you checking if the select has the correct id? The 2nd option should have done the trick `$("#HoldItemsArr option:selected").prop("selected", false);`

Comment: @KhaldounNd I checked the id and is fine any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The link below help with what I was looking for

[How do I reset a jquery-chosen select option with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery)

I needed to add the code below to my JavaScript

$('#HoldItemsArr').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
$("#HoldItemsArr").multiselect("clearSelection");
```

Option 2:

```
$("#HoldItemsArr option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("#HoldItemsArr").multiselect('refresh');
```