# Why is it items added in a @Html.DropDownListFor with jQuery do not appear?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add items in a `@Html.DropDownListFor` with jQuery but after adding them they don't appear. Looking at the inspector of Chrome to debug code all items are being added, but in page they don't appear. I tried to update the select after to add the items but it still doesn't work.

How could I fix this?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="cols-sm-10">
  <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.cartaoCheckout.ParcelamentoSelecionado)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Parcelas <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend w-75">
      <span class="input-group-text" style="height:40px;"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></span> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cartaoCheckout.ParcelamentoSelecionado, Model.cartaoCheckout.Parcelamentos, "-Parcelamento-", new { Class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cartaoCheckout.ParcelamentoSelecionado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
var dados = data["ParcelamentoCartao"];
var _select = $('#cartaoCheckout_ParcelamentoSelecionado');
_select.empty();

$.each(dados["Parcelamentos"], function(i, item) {
  console.log(item.quantity);
  _select.append('<option value="' + item.quantity + '">' + item.quantity + '</option>');
  _select.trigger("liszt:updated");
  _select.trigger("chosen:updated");
});
_select.trigger("liszt:updated");
_select.trigger("chosen:updated");
```

** EDIT - below the Chrome Inspect output**

```
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Parcelamento must be a number." data-val-required="Informe o número de parcelas" id="cartaoCheckout_ParcelamentoSelecionado" name="cartaoCheckout.ParcelamentoSelecionado" style="display: none;">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

**Image with select empty even after execute jQuery**

[image]

**Here the image debugging Chrome's inspector. The select has the options added with jQuery**

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot of the "select" doesn't look like a `select` - are you converting it / wrapping it (eg using chosen/select2)?

Comment: Looks like you're doing *something* `_select.trigger("chosen:updated");` ?  Please include exactly what plugins you're using *and* which versions (`liszt:updated` was apparently removed ~10 years ago....)  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery/11365340#11365340

Comment: Please show code as text, not as a picture of text. In Chrome, you can right-click an element and select Copy > Copy outerHTML to get the element as text. I note that the element you have highlighted here has `style="display: none;"`, which tells me that, as @freedomn-m has intuited, that `select` is not what is getting displayed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have already edit adding the outerHtml  of chrome

Comment: @freedomn-m nope, it is just a `@Html.DropDownListFor` . I ain't use any plugin, just jquery and razor

Comment: Then what's this code for? `_select.trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: Also, look *closely* at your own pasted html - right at the end `style="display: none;"` - confirms: your *actual* `select` is being hidden and replaced by another control - as obvious on the UI, but incase you need more proof: right click the control and do `inspect element` - it will go to a `div` that appears *next to* your `select` - that's not an error.

Comment: @freedomn-m just was test. But now, I think that the problem is with jquery because I tried to use `empty()` to clean the select and it doesn't works

Comment: Your next step is to provide a [mcve] that **demonstrates the problem** as, if we take your code as-is it will clearly work (as you're expecting it to, hence your question)

Comment: Here's your code (with a `data` object implied that you didn't provide).  You *say* `display:none` was just a test, so that's removed.  You *say* you don't have any plugins (despite `chosen:updated` and `class=form-control` showing otherwise, perhaps they are just "tests" as well - maybe provide *actual* code, so we don't have to guess what's a test and what isn't) so those are commented.   Trying to help you, but you're not making it easy.